# Can I send a csrf cookie-token from javascript to a Django api?

Tags: django, csrf

I have a SAP (written in the Svelte framework) and presented by Netlify. The business logic and data is handled by a Django app. So far I have only used GET and everything works well. But now I want to upload a file's content and use POST. When I try to POST to the Django app I get a 403 error, specifically:

```
WARNING:django.security.csrf:Forbidden (Origin checking failed - http://localhost:8888 does not match any trusted origins.): /test-put/
```

I think I have overcome any CORS issues ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75834983/cannot-use-fetch-with-django-blocked-by-cors-policy-although-cors-is-set-up-in/75840592#75840592)).

The call to the Djnago API is

**javascript**

```
async function sendDataToAPI(payload) {
    let endpoint = 'http://192.168.4.28:8000/test-put/'
    const form_data = new FormData();

    form_data.append("payload", payload);

    await fetch(endpoint, {
        credentials: "same-origin",
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            data: payload,
        }),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("Success:", result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    });
}


function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

**urls.py**

```
path('test-put/', views.TestPut.as_view()),
```

**views.py**

```
class TestPut(View):
    def put(self, request):
        return {}
```

Of course, the webpage calling the POST is NOT  a Django template, so is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

3 months in so I don't know if you still need this, but CORS and CSRF are related - but different things.

You can find a thorough explanation, with examples, [here](https://maddevs.io/blog/web-security-an-overview-of-sop-cors-and-csrf/).

You didn't show your `settings.py` configuration so is hard to guess what it might be missing but [Django has a setting called `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins) - which is different from `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` (both should be set if you plan on working with forms).

My guess would be on configuring `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` adding `http://localhost:8888` to it and double-checking your `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`. Both should have your localhost configured to allow requests coming in.

And just to be thorough, do remember that this setup is for LOCAL development only.